# Adding/changing logic in send_email method within django-registration-redux

Tags: django, django-registration

My site runs multiple domains. Users can register on each of these domains. As a result, I need to make django-registration-redux:

- use the correct email address for sending registration/password reset emails
- use the correct email password for sending registration/password reset emails
- use the correct domain within registration/password reset emails

I've been digging into the source code for django-registration-redux and believe that I need to update the send_email method within registration/models.py (https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/blob/master/registration/models.py) with my required changes.

I'm assuming the best way to add this cusomtization is as follows:

- run 'pip uninstall django-registration-redux==2.2'
- run 'pip freeze > requirements.txt'
- from the source code, pull the 'registration' folder into my project
- go into myproject/registration/models.py and manually update the send_email method so that it includes my changes.

Is there an easier or more correct way to build my custom logic into def send_email without making the changes noted above?

Thanks!

Comment: So you have the modification you want, but you just want to see how best to use it?

Comment: what is current status and what are you expecting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to add a context processor that grabs the company name and website based on the current website, which can be accessed via request, and then reference the context variable within the django-registration email templates :)

Comment: This is a good solution. I was just missing the details :)

Add a file `my_ctx_proc.py` to your application `myapp`:

```
def get_info_email(request):
    return {
       'info_email': "info@" + request.META['HTTP_HOST'],
    }
```

In your `settings.py`, add in `TEMPLATES` `OPTIONS` `context_processors` at the end:

```
'myapp.my_ctx_proc.get_info_email',
```

Now you can insert `{{ info_email }}` in your email template.

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass the model then override the function that calls `send_email()` and patch it with your custom function.

```
from unittest import mock
from django_registration import models

def custom_send_email():
    print('sending custom email')

class CustomEmailRegistration(models.Registration):
    def function_calling_send_email(self):
        with mock.patch('models.send_email', side_effect=custom_send_email):
            super().function_calling_send_email()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you add a context processor that gets the current hostname from the request:

Add a file `my_ctx_proc.py` to your application `myapp`:

```
def get_info_email(request):
    return {
       'info_email': "info@" + request.META['HTTP_HOST'],
    }
```

In your `settings.py`, add in `TEMPLATES` `OPTIONS` `context_processors` at the end:

```
'myapp.my_ctx_proc.get_info_email',
```

Now you can insert `{{ info_email }}` in your email template, eg. `templates/django_registration/activation_body_email.txt`